# CLion how to set code insight as Linux on Windows?

Tags: clion

I'm using CLion on Windows but have a Linux project. There's no remote environment to build (and I don't need to build it). I just want to read the code. But some .h files has #ifndef _WINDOWS64, CLion code insight will ignore them, tells me cannot find declaration to go to and highlight almost every function red. How to configure the project as a Linux project? It's a CMake project.

Comment: If your code has `_WIN64` header guards, it is calling windows api within that code, meaning you somehow need access to windows api on linux. That being said, you might want to have a look at [winelib](https://dl.winehq.org/wine/docs/en/winelib-guide.html) for windows libs on linux. [Wine](https://www.winehq.org/) implements a lot of the windows api, so it might just be what you are looking for.

Comment: @Mubin No, the project does not contain any windows api. However, it uses some linux api, so the fuctions are after #ifndef _WINDOWS64. I'm using CLion on Windows, and CLion auto ignored these functions. I did not find anycode defines _WINDOWS64. It seems CLion auto recognize my platfrom is Windows64